# When the actual download occurs for a Http Request

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, http-request

I am downloading a zip file from Amazon S3. Then I convert this zip to `MemoryStream`. My code is below

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(basicAwsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(item.RegionEndPoint));
//This operation needs about 3-4s
response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
//This operation needs about 8-9s
await response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

My connection speed about 70-80KBs. I want to know why coping to memory stream takes too much time?

My another question is when the actual download occurs in any http request? when I get the response object or when I copy the Stream from response object?

#### Edit

I am actually downloading a zip file from AWS S3 and using the MemoryStream to unzip the file like this-

```
var zipStream = new ZipInputStream(memoryStream);
```

Size of my zip is around 2MB. So which operation will be faster? Save the zip into file system, then extract or extract from MemoryStream directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My connection speed about 70-80KBs. I want to know why coping to
>   memory stream takes too much time?

Hard to answer this question. If the file you are downloading is too big, copying it to memory would incur some garbage collection which comes with the corresponding overhead of course. Obviously streaming the file to some other `Stream` such as a `FileStream` or a `NetworkStream` (depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve and your specific requirements) might improve the performance and even allow you to download multiple files at a time from Amazon without busting all your available RAM and forcing the Operating System into swapping the crap out of it on the disk.

> My another question is when the actual download occurs in any http
>   request? when I get the response object or when I copy the Stream from
>   response object?

When you `await` on the `CopyToAsync` method call. The `CopyToAsync` method will copy small byte chunks from the source stream to the destination stream until it reaches the end of the source stream. But since your destination `Stream` is a `MemoryStream` you are of course losing all the benefits of this chunked copying because you end up with the entire file loaded into your process operating memory.

Comment: Size of my file is around 2MB. "CopyToAsync() method will copy small byte chunks". I want to know from where this byte chunks comes. From my response object, or from Server?

Comment: Since the Amazon client is making an HTTP call, your source stream is a `NetworkStream`. In .NET, a `NetworkStream` is just a pointer to the underlying Socket data. So you are basically copying chunks of bytes from this socket into your process memory (a `MemoryStream`). And if you are interested into the exact size of those chunks you might consult the documentation of the [`CopyToAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158751(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you are using which more than clearly states that this chunk size is 81920 bytes.

Comment: Please see Edit section of my question and help me.

Comment: Save the downloaded file to the file system (`FileStream`) and then unzip it from there.